# in android studio i keep getting the message my Haxm no matter how many time I install it

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, cross-platform

after installing the message below gets outputted. yet after every time it still shows that I didn't download it, I have even restarted my computer and it still shows this. I also checked in my command prompt and it shows that -Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes- so I don't believe the VT is the issue

```
Preparing "Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.6.5)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/haxm-windows_v7_6_5.zip
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.6.5)" ready.
Installing Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) in C:\Users\Mohamed Rezki\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.6.5)" complete.
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.6.5)" finished.
Parsing C:\Users\Mohamed Rezki\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\32.0.0\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\Mohamed Rezki\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\32.1.0-rc1\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\Mohamed Rezki\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\Mohamed Rezki\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\Mohamed Rezki\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\Mohamed Rezki\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\patcher\v4\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\Mohamed Rezki\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\Mohamed Rezki\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-32\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\Mohamed Rezki\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-32\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\package.xml
Android SDK is up to date.
Running Intel® HAXM installer
Intel HAXM installed successfully!
Done
```

Comment: HAXM does not work without VT-x (Virtual Technology) you need toenable it from your BIOS

Comment: @JunaidKhalid I checked in my command prompt and it shows that -Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes- so i don't believe the VT is the issue